# is there a way to search a text file a number between two numbers (dates) in php?

Tags: php

I currently have the ability to chose a 'to' and 'from' date on my webpage:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      if(document.getElementById("from").type == "text") {
        var maxDate = new Date();
        var minDate = new Date("2012-01-01");
        $("#from").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          maxDate: maxDate,
          minDate: minDate,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          showMonthAfterYear: true,
          showOtherMonths: true,
          selectOtherMonths: true,
          onClose: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
          }
        });
        $("#to").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          maxDate: maxDate,
          minDate: minDate,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          showMonthAfterYear: true,
          showOtherMonths: true,
          selectOtherMonths: true,
          onClose: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        $("#from").on("change", function() {
          $("#to").prop("min", $(this).val());
        });
        $("#to").on("change", function(){
          $("#from").prop("max", $(this).val());
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
<form action="" form method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Select dates?" name="dates"/>
    Search Between Dates? (only available if 'Finished' is selected)

                <label for="from">From:</label>
                <input id="from" name="from" type="date" value="2015-05-25"/>

            </div>


                <label for="to">To:</label>
                <input id="to" name="to" type="date" value="2015-06-24"/>
</form>
```

I was wondering if I can use the entry from the to and from boxes to search a text file for any dates between the two. My text file looks something like this (with lots more entries) The first column is the date:

```
20150619    finished    17772   resolved    philw       Current/17772 - 
20150619    finished    17751   resolved    peters      Current/17751 - 
20150619    finished    17594   resolved    peters      Current/17594 - 
unfinished  unfinished  16218   open        allanm      Current/16218 - 
unfinished  unfinished  15918   open        allanm      Current/15918 -
```

Came up with an answer:

```
    // Set $fromdate to the entered value if there was one, otherwise set it to something long ago
$fromdate = $_REQUEST["from"] ? $_REQUEST["from"] : date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-100 years"));

// Set $todate to the entered value if there was one, otherwise set it to tomorrow. There shouldn't be any finished dates in the future!
$todate = $_REQUEST["to"] ? $_REQUEST["to"]: date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"));

// Remove the hyphens so that our dates are in the same format as the text file and we can compare them directly
$fromdate = str_replace("-", "", $fromdate);
$todate = str_replace("-", "", $todate);

 $handle = @fopen("project-list.txt", "r");

while(!feof($handle)) {
  $row = fgets($handle);

$col1 = explode ("\t", $row);

  if(($col1 != "unfinished") && ($col1 >= $fromdate) && ($col1 <= $todate))
     // Or save the $row in an array to write out later

         echo $row;

}

 fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether or not you can guarantee the dates in your text file will always be sorted in a particular order. One way is to read the file line-by-line until you find the matching start date and continue to store the consecutive lines until you have either reached the end date or the end of the file. The other way, if you the file isn't sorted, is to load all lines from the file into an array and sort them by date.

## Sorted File Approach

```
$collect = false;
$n       = 1;
$file    = 'myfile.txt';
$fp      = fopen($file, 'r');
$data    = [];

while($line = fgets($fp)) {
    list($date, $data) = explode("\t", $line, 2); // assumption of tab delimiter
    try {
        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Ymd', $date);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Encountered bad date form on line $n in $file!\n";
    }
    if ($date == $to) {
        $collect = true;
    }
    if ($date == $from) {
        break;
    }
    if ($collect) {
        $data[] = $line;
    }
    $n++;
}

// do whatever with $data here
```

## Unsorted File Approach

```
$fileName = 'myfile.txt';
$data = file($fileName);
$data = array_map(function($line) {
          list($date, $data) = explode("\t", $line);
          $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Ymd', $date);
          return ['date' => $date->getTimestamp(), 'line' => $line];
        }, $data);
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['date'] < $b['date']) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($a['date'] > $b['date']) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

$data = array_filter($data, function($v) use($to, $from) {
    return $v['date'] >= $to && $v['date'] <= $from;
});

// Anything left in $data at this point is between $to and $from
```

Comment: Thanks Sherif, I have tried running this and it says:
Notice: Undefined variable: to in C:\projectlist\test1.php on line 499

Notice: Undefined variable: from in C:\projectlist\test1.php on line 502
unfinished 17876 open peters Current/17876 - AddressBase Plus data changes in Sept 2015

Comment: Sorry I have changed it to the bottom scripts you provided and it says :
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean in C:\projectlist\test1.php on line 492 @Sherif

Comment: That means that `DateTime:;createFromFormat` failed. You can inspect the variables by using `var_dump` and work your way backwards to figure out where things went wrong.

Comment: Ahh I think its because some lines in my text files don't have a date in, instead they say 'unfinished'. Is there anyway around that? @Sherif

Comment: I have updated the text file in my question to show you @Sherif